# Calculate $ f [f (x)] $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Where $ f (x) = \frac {1} {1 + x ^ 2} $, $ f [f (x)] $ is equal to:
a

I was factoring and found $f(f(x))= \frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{1+x^2})^2} = \frac{1}{\frac{x^4+2x^2+2}{x^4+2x^2+1}}= \frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^4+2x^2+2}$, but the answer is x. I am wrong?

Comment: I’m pretty sure the answer is not $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of

$$f(f(x))=\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^4+2x^2+2}$$

is correct. Both the numerator and denominator are fourth degree polynomials with a coefficient of $1$ before the $x^4$ term. Therefore, there is a horizontal asymptote at $y=1$.

So, the answer cannot be $f(f(x))=x$. As the graph of $f(f(x))$ is bounded above by $y=1$, it cannot be equal to the value of $x$ when $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not $x$, as Desmos (and the rest of math!) suggest(s):

[image]

Comment: I think we are supposed to solve the equation: $$\frac{x^4+2x^2+1}{x^4+2x^2+2}=x$$

Comment: But note that it must hold for all values of $x$. For sufficiently large $x$, it does not clearly hold.